# How do you change the name of a root element in JSON with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to change the variable name of this:

```
var grid = { 
    "name": "test", 
    "columns":
    [
        {"name":"col1"},
        {"name":"col2"}
    ], 
    "rows":
    [
         {"name":"col1", "value":"text1"},
         {"name":"col2", "value":"text2"}
    ] 
}
```

I want to change grid to grid1.  Is this possible? Thanks for your guidance here. I did research this and did not find any solutions out there.

Comment: I can't think why you'd want to **change** the name once you've declared it. You don't have to call it `grid`, just make sure you keep the same name wherever you use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really JSON; it's just a JavaScript object. So "grid" is just a JavaScript variable. You can copy it to a variable with a different name, and delete the original, like this:

```
var grid1 = grid;
delete grid;
```